# Sliding window on a 2D data

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a file of shape

```
(97500, 91)
```

I need to slice this file using sliding window of length 100 and step of 100,so I am expecting output of shape

```
(975,100,91)
```

Instead I get a shape of

```
(876,100,91)
```

Am I expecting something wrong and my codes are right or vice versa?

Here is how am doing it

```
import scipy.io
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
data=scipy.io.loadmat('input file.mat')
x=data['header name']
x = x.reshape(91, -1)
x = np.transpose(x, (1,0))
print(x.shape) #(97500, 91)
def moving_window(x, length, step=100):
    streams = it.tee(x, length)
    return zip(*[it.islice(stream, i, None, step) for stream, i in zip(streams, it.count(step=step))])
X=list(moving_window(x, 100))
X=np.asarray(X)
print(X.shape)#(876,100,91)
```

Comment: A sliding window can't go from (97500, 91) to (975,100,91). That's a blocky window ( no overlap).

Comment: Yes,That is why I use window size 100 and step 100 to avoid overlapping. But in my Understanding if you chop a 97500 long data into pieces of 100 you will results into 975 pieces,that is where my confusion is.

Comment: Simply reshape : `np.reshape(arr, (975,100,91))`?

Comment: Looks like your range or count iterator is not including the 'end' point.   It's one 100 size block short.  But if reshape works you don't need correct that detail.